# Check if fields have valid class and are not empty before enabling submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I asked this question earlier with no luck, so I am trying again with better wording and hopefully I can resolve my issue.

I have been working on a small form which has a few inputs, three of which have regex validation (`email`, `number` and `postcode`). I have a function which checks if all fields in the form are filled before enabling the submit button, however if the previously mentioned fields are invalid (but filled), the button will still be enabled and allow submission. I am looking to try and incorporate a check if the fields are **also** valid before enabling the submit button.

I have been trying at this since 7am with no luck, I have tried checking if they have class `is-invalid` to disable button, I tried to implement the jQuery Validate plugin (which I didn't find very useful), and really I have hit a bit of a wall and don't know what else to do.

I can find plenty of answers on checking valid input, and plenty on checking if forms are filled completely, but none which incorporate both, and I've tried to do it myself and it's not working. Any help is, as always, appreciated.

Here's what I have:

```js
// ~~~ phone number validation

function validateContact(number) {
  var re = /^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/;
  return re.test(number);
}

function validateC() {
  var number = $("#number").val();

  if (validateContact(number)) {
    $("#number").removeClass("is-invalid");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a valid phone number');
    $("#number").addClass("is-invalid");
  }
  return false;
}

// ~~~ email validation

function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validateE() {
  var email = $("#email").val();

  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#email").removeClass("is-invalid");
    //        $("#submit").removeClass("toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", false);
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a valid email address.');
    $("#email").addClass("is-invalid");
    //        $("#submit").addClass("toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", true);
  }
  return false;
}

// ~~~ postcode validation

function validatePostcode(postcode) {
  var re = /^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Za-z]{0,1} {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2}$/;
  return re.test(postcode);
}

function validateP() {
  var postcode = $("#postcode").val();

  if (validatePostcode(postcode)) {
    $("#postcode").removeClass("is-invalid");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a valid postcode');
    $("#postcode").addClass("is-invalid");
  }
  return false;
}

// ~~~ validate if form is filled completely, toggles submit & edit button

$(document).on('change keyup', '.required', function(e) {
  var disabled = true;
  // var isValid = false;

  $(".required").each(function() {
    var value = this.value;

    if ((value) && (value.trim() != '')) {
      disabled = false;
      $('.toggle-disabled').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      disabled = true;
      $('.toggle-disabled').prop("disabled", true);
      return false;
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="email" class="input form-control required" id="email" onchange="validateE()" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="tel" class="input number form-control required" id="number" onchange="validateC()" placeholder="Contact Number" name="Number" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="text" id="postcode" class="input postcode form-control required" onchange="validateP()" placeholder="Post Code" name="postcode" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input id="submit" class="btn btn-danger toggle-disabled" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `&&` use `||` because here if any one of the condition is `true` you need to disable your submit button . Then , add one extra condition `$(this).hasClass('is-invalid'))` for checking if the inputs are valid or not .

***Demo code*** :

```js
// ~~~ phone number validation

function validateContact(number) {
  var re = /^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/;
  return re.test(number);
}

function validateC() {
  var number = $("#number").val();

  if (validateContact(number)) {
    $("#number").removeClass("is-invalid");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a valid phone number');
    $("#number").addClass("is-invalid");
  }
  return false;
}

// ~~~ email validation

function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validateE() {
  var email = $("#email").val();

  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#email").removeClass("is-invalid");
    //        $("#submit").removeClass("toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", false);
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a valid email address.');
    $("#email").addClass("is-invalid");
    //        $("#submit").addClass("toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", true);
  }
  return false;
}

// ~~~ postcode validation

function validatePostcode(postcode) {
  var re = /^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Za-z]{0,1} {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2}$/;
  return re.test(postcode);
}

function validateP() {
  var postcode = $("#postcode").val();

  if (validatePostcode(postcode)) {
    $("#postcode").removeClass("is-invalid");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a valid postcode');
    $("#postcode").addClass("is-invalid");
  }
  return false;
}

// ~~~ validate if form is filled completely, toggles submit & edit button

$(document).on('change keyup', '.required', function(e) {
  var disabled = true;
  $(".required").each(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    //using or also added hasclass('is-invalid')
    if (!(value) || (value.trim() === '') || ($(this).hasClass('is-invalid'))) {
      disabled = false;
      $('.toggle-disabled').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
  //check disabled if true then also enabled.
  if (disabled) {
    $('.toggle-disabled').prop("disabled", false);
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="email" class="input form-control required" id="email" onchange="validateE()" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="tel" class="input number form-control required" id="number" onchange="validateC()" placeholder="Contact Number" name="Number" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="text" id="postcode" class="input postcode form-control required" onchange="validateP()" placeholder="Post Code" name="postcode" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input id="submit" class="btn btn-danger toggle-disabled" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```